# Sprichwörtlich! Warum benutzen so viele Menschen das Wort, wenn sie Redewendungen benutzen?

Tags: word-usage

Ich weiß, es ist falsch und sprachlich unschön, Sprichwörter mit dem Wort *sprichwörtlich* zu ergänzen. Es heißt z.B.: ***Er kriegt nichts gebacken!*** und nicht: ***Er kriegt sprichwörtlich nichts gebacken!*** Man muss nicht jedes Sprichwort mit diesem Wort markieren. Dies tun allerdings sehr viele Menschen, auch in den Medien. Das Wort ist nur dann zu benutzen, wenn es sich auf Sprichwörter bezieht, z.B. ***Sprichwörtliche Vergleiche verbessern den Stil eines Textes.***

### Frage: Warum benutzen so viele Menschen das Wort *sprichwörtlich* falsch?

Ist es zur Abschwächung des Sprichwortes? Am nervigsten ist die Verwendung des Wortes in Situationen, in denen sich ein *sprichwörtliches* Wort nicht mal auf ein [Sprichwort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprichwort) bezieht. Beispiel: ***Das ist sprichwörtlich ein Nagel zu seinem Sarg.*** Kennt ihr ein Sprichwort über einen Nagel und einen Sarg? Ich nicht. Das ist eine *Redewendung*. Ein Sprichwort wäre z.B. ***Hunger ist der beste Koch.*** Und selbst in diesem Beispiel, warum sollte man sagen ***Hunger ist sprichwörtlich der beste Koch***? Das Wort ist dort vollkommen überflüssig. Jeder weiß, dass es ein Sprichwort ist, jeder versteht es.

Duden listet zwei Bedeutungen des Wortes aus:

> 1. fast zu einer Floskel geworden; proverbiell
> 2. allgemein bekannt; häufig zitiert

Erlaubt eine dieser Definition die, in meiner Meinung, falsche Verwendung des Wortes *sprichwörtlich* zur Markierung der Sprichwörter, wenn sie benutzt werden?

***Beispiele.***
Ich habe heute in einem Text Folgendes gelesen:

> ...damit wir all diese Punkte sprichwörtich auf dem "Schirm" haben.

Sogar noch mit Anführungsstrichen! Sprichwörtlich eine Katastrophe....

> ***Sprichwörtlich überflüssiger Appendix doch nicht so überflüssig***
>
> Der Wurmfortsatz (Appendix) des Menschen galt bisher immer als
> typisches Beispiel für ein Organ, das die Evolution auszurotten
> vergessen hat. Er sei absolut nutzlos und könne ohne Folgen entfernt
> werden, hat man immer gelernt. Aber dass das gar nicht so ist,

Eine weitere Katastrophe. Es gibt kein Sprichwort über einen überflüssigen Appendix, ja nicht mal eine Redewendung. ([Quelle](http://joeshoe.blogspot.de/2008/02/sprichwrtlich-berflssiger-appendix-doch.html))

Comment: Ja, ich stimme mit der Meinung von Barth ueberein, dass die Leute "sprichwoertlich" mit buchstaeblich verwechseln!
Enttäuschend, dass es noch nicht mal in Nachrichtensendungen korrekt angewandt wird…

Comment: Irgendwo unter dem, was sich wie eine kulturpessimistische Polemik gegen die Falschverwendung eines Wortes liest, versteckt sich tatsächlich eine Frage. Es wäre aber schön, könnte man die Wortwahl der Frage etwas weniger herablassend formulieren; dann wäre sie mir vielleicht einen Upvote wert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meines Erachtens geht es hier weniger um "richtig" oder "falsch" sondern eher um Geschmacksfragen bzw. subjektiv guten/schlechten Stil.

Für eine ernstzunehmende Antwort wären zudem *echte* Beispiele aus externen Quellen sinnvoll. Von den aktuell in der Frage aufgezählten ergibt kein einziges einen Google-Treffer – es sieht also nach eigenen Formulierungen aus. Sehe ich das richtig?

Je länger ich drüber nachdenke, desto weniger wahrscheinlich kommt mir die beschriebene Verwendung vor. Kann es sein, dass statt "sprichwörtlich" "buchstäblich" gemeint ist?
Damit würden die genannten Beispiele deutlich vertrauter klingen.

---

Andere Möglichkeit: Wortstellung

> … damit wir all diese Punkte sprichwörtlich auf dem "Schirm" haben.

Meines Erachtens würden die meisten Sprecher das so sagen:

> … damit wir all diese Punkte auf dem sprichwörtlichen "Schirm" haben.

Das ist zwar nicht der Gipfel an sprachlicher Eleganz, entspricht aber der Duden-Definition, da "etwas auf dem Schirm haben" absolut zu einer Floskel geworden ist.

Beim Appendix ist wohl gemeint, dass der Blinddarm von vielen für so *überflüssig wie der sprichwörtliche Kropf* gehalten wird. Wiederum nicht brillant formuliert aber m. E. absolut nicht "falsch".

### Fazit:

Ich glaube "falsch" ist ein bisschen übertrieben. Die Formulierung mag oft nicht sonderlich schön sein – in vielen Fällen dürfte das aber am sprachlichen Stil der betreffenden Aussage insgesamt liegen, nicht am einzelnen Wörtchen "sprichwörtlich".

Answer (score 0):

Wenn man Schirm dann in Anführungszeichen setzt, ist das sicherlich sehr fragwürdig.

Nur, was hast du denn gegen das Wort sprichwörtlich? Das ist ein ganz normales im Duden stehendes Adjektiv. Dein Beispielsatz ist (abgesehen von den Anführungszeichen bei "Schirm") nicht falsch.

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sprichwoertlich

Wie kommst du denn überhaupt auf die Idee, dass man dieses Adjektiv nicht verwenden sollte?

Comment: Weil es heißt: ***Er kriegt nichts gebacken!*** und nicht: ***Er kriegt sprichwörtlich nichts gebacken.*** Man muss nicht jedes Sprichwort mit diesem Wort markieren. Das tun aber erstaunlich viele Menschen, auch in Medien. Das Wort ist nur dann zu benutzen, wenn es sich auf Sprichwörter bezieht, z.B. ***Sprichwörtliche Vergleiche verbesseren den Stil eines Textes.***

Comment: Ok, mir war jetzt nicht so klar, dass du auf die Semantik hinaus wolltest, sorry. Die Frage, ob Adjektive sinnvoll sind oder nicht, weil sie nicht zum Kontext passen, ist ja eine ganz allgemeine Frage unabhängig vom Wort sprichwörtlich.
"Das Wort ist nur dann zu benutzen, wenn es sich auf Sprichwörter bezieht" Ist das wirklich so? 
Kann ich ein volles Glas Wasser füllen? Das wäre grammatisch korrekt, aber natürlich Unsinn. Der Duden schreibt bei den Bedeutungen von sprichwörtlich jedoch nicht etwa "Auf ein Sprichwort bezogen" sondern unter anderem "allgemein bekannt; häufig zitiert".